# Interpreting S and P in MATLAB spectrogram

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I've been trying to better understand the following use of MATLAB's `spectrogram()`:

```
[S,F,T,P] = spectrogram(x,window,noverlap,f,fs)
```

Assume `x` is real. From what I understand, `P` is the PSD estimate of `x` (equivalent to using `pwelch()`?) while the columns of `S` are the STFT of Hamming windows along `x`. `P` appears to be proportional to the square root of the magnitude of `S`.

Where did this proportionality factor come from? What are the "units" of `P` and `S`, respectively?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at [`spectrogram`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html) in MATLAB Documentation.

But Spectrograms are 2D functions, time and frequency.
The `S` represent the DFT of the Samples of time vector `T` with respect to frequencies on Frequency Vector `W`.
Since you use Window, the result is of the windowed time samples.

The `P` vector is for the PSD (Squared absolute value of `S`) on the same windowed samples and frequencies.

Comment: I have read the documentation. It doesn't say why the `P` vector is only proportional to (not equal to) the squared absolute value of `S` in general for the particular form of `spectrogram()` I used in the question.

Comment: I copy from the documentation: `[___,ps] = spectrogram(___) also returns a matrix, ps, containing an estimate of the power spectral density (PSD) or the power spectrum of each section.`. They say it is estimation since the PSD requires the whole signal $ \left( - \infty, \infty \right) $.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned S is STFT of windowed x, and P is PSD.

P can be calculated by S.

You can find the calculation background here. [here](http://www.fhnw.ch/technik/ime/publikationen/2012/how-to-use-the-fft-and-matlab2019s-pwelch-function-for-signal-and-noise-simulations-and-measurements)

Below example shows how to calculate P from S.

```
t = 0:0.001:2;
x = chirp(t,0,1,150); % 2 second chirp signal

nfft=256;

cFactor=0.3974; % Noise gain of hamming window

[S,F,T,P] = spectrogram(x,nfft,100,nfft,1e3); % S is STFT of hamming windowed signal

fbin=F(2)-F(1); %Frequency resolution

nS=(1/(2*(nfft/2+1)))*S; % normalizing by length of S

Pxx=2*(1/fbin)*(1/cFactor)*nS.*conj(nS);  %PSD of AC value

Pxx(1,:)=(1/fbin)*(1/cFactor)*nS(1,:).*conj(nS(1,:)); %PSD of DC value
```

Here, Pxx variable will be the same with P variable.

You can check the result by using below graph

```
figure(1)
subplot(2,1,1)
waterfall(F,T,P')
xlabel('frequency(Hz)')
ylabel('time(sec)')

figure(1)
subplot(2,1,2)
waterfall(F,T,real(Pxx)')
xlabel('frequency(Hz)')
ylabel('time(sec)')
```

Pwelch function also gives PSD and calculation method is the same with spectrogram, except doing averaging all STFT.

If you do use pwelch function in the same way with upper example you will find averaged graph of all STFT segments.

Please, try below code with same signal to see how pwelch works.

```
t = 0:0.001:2;
x = chirp(t,0,1,150); % 2 second chirp signal

nfft=256;
[P,F] = pwelch(x,nfft,100,nfft,1e3); 

figure(2)
plot(F,P)
xlabel('frequency(Hz)')
```

In figure(2), you will see average graph of figure(1) waterfall graph.

Regarding unit of S and P,

S doesn't have unit, because DFT doesn't care unit.

P is square of rms value of time signal per Hz.

If time signal unit is Volt(V), unit of P is Vrms^2/Hz.